# Plone workflow for "door-keeper" pattern where parent folder permissions are respected

Tags: plone

I'd like to have an workflow for content type which would respect the parent folder permissions. Is there one available out of the box or do I need to create my own?

This would be "door-keeper" so that if the parent folder is private and has local roles for certain users/groups only then only those users would be able to view items in this folder.

I think the options are

- Create a custom content item and create workflow for it
- CMFPlacefulWorkflow which defines a special workflow for the folder only

... but someone with more experience might like to eloborate.

http://blog.keul.it/2011/10/plone-security-and-workflows-learn-how.html

Plone 4.x.

Comment: My old article you cited contains my answer, so I probably don't get the real problem there. Plone workflow are out-of-the-box broken, but designing a new one with proper acquire is not so hard. Or: I'm missing something.

Comment: @Mikko Just in case if you are writing you own workflow try [ftw.lawgiver](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.lawgiver) it lets you define the workflow in a human readable spec. But it does not cover everything the WorkflowTool can do. But maybe it saves you a lot of time :-)